# Why the binding fails for layout_marginEnd but not for layout_marginStart?

Tags: android

So I'm using binding to let my layout can be changed dynamically. And I bind my view's margin like this
`android:layout_marginStart="@{model.showAvatar ? @dimen/default_padding : @dimen/without_avatar_start_margin}"` However I can only apply this to margin start, if I apply the same logic to margin end it will gives me compilation error like this `Found data binding errors.Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_marginEnd' with parameter type float on com.xx.ui.widget.TextView.`
 Any explanation?

Comment: Is it the same dimensions for both? Maybe you used float dimensions for marginEnd and integer dimensions for marginStart? The error says it couldn't find a `setMarginEnd(float)` method, which means it tries to set a float.

Comment: @Nicolas I put exactly the same string or say value to margin end which are integers. Then it gives this error. That's the thing I don't understand, why it gave me float error...

Answer (score 1):

maybe with Android studio 3.0 final release, the databinding still doesn't work for the custom views generated by androidannotations

But you can using @BindingAdapter instead

```
@BindingAdapter(value = { "android:layout_marginEnd", "android:layout_marginStart" })
public static void setLayoutMargin(View view, float marginEnd, float marginStart) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parameter =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    parameter.setMargins((int) marginEnd, parameter.topMargin, (int) marginStart,
            parameter.bottomMargin);
    view.setLayoutParams(parameter);
}
```

Its not better way but hope this helps

Comment: I later found a solution that only uses margin start and avoided using margin end. But I do think you solution is viable. I didn't accept this answer because I want to know why there is different between margin start and margin end.